# Confirm UPDATE of row in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I searched this but found so many different answers and none work.

I am trying to get a TRUE OR FALSE if the row was updated or not by checking my $result var.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE iMember SET 
cellPhoneConfirmed='true' WHERE iMemberID = '$iMemberID'") or die("shoot");
```

Comment: `mysqli_affected_rows($link)` contains number of affected rows

Comment: but how do I use this in php? Just like that and I check the $link var?

Comment: `if(mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0){ //updated }`

Comment: if(mysqli_affected_rows($result) > 0){
    $confirmed = true;
  } - this did not work

Comment: `$link` is a connection such as `$con` in your example :)

Comment: If you answer in the right place I will give you the check :) Thank you soooo much

Comment: Readers should be aware of the security risks of copying this code - if `$iMemberID` is tainted with unfiltered user input, there may be a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score -1):

mysqli_query() normally returns 1 for true and 0 for false.

if your variable $iMemberID is an integer no need for qoutes.

```
'$iMemberID' to $iMemberID
```

Like this..

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE iMember SET 
cellPhoneConfirmed='true' WHERE iMemberID = $iMemberID") or die("shoot");
```

Comment: mysqli_query is just for checking the query, but a query might run smoothly without updating any rows...